# How to write custom logs when message is enqueued & dequeued in ActiveMQ

Tags: c#, .net, log4j, activemq-classic

When I enqueue/dequeue message ActiveMQ writes a log in `<ACTIVEMQ_HOME>/data/activemq.log`

```
2020-03-03 12:59:36,505 |  test001              | DEBUG | queue://test001, subscriptions=0, memory=0%, size=172, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, force:false, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 172, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 172, enqueueCount: 200, dequeueCount: 28, memUsage:178980, maxPageSize:200 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-23
```

If I send one message to ActiveMQ, lets say "Test", I want to write `publisher name(hostname) message` in log file. Also if I have multiple consumer (e.g. consumer1, consumer2, etc.) then I want to write `consumer name(hostname)` in the log file when it dequeues a message.

Comment: @JustinBertram
Thanks for editing question.
If I send one message to ActiveMQ, lets say "Test".
I want to write publisher name(hostname) & message in log file.

Also if I have multiple consumer(consumer1, consumer2, ....)
then I want to write consumer name(hostname) in log file which dequeue above message.

Comment: The publisher and consumer applications as well as the Log4j configuration is  completely irrelevant here. The broker itself logs the information, not the clients. I've simplified the question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @JustinBertram
Once again thanks for helping me & also for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 1):

It still unclear exactly what you are trying to achieve here but close as I can guess is you want something along the lines of a custom [Logging Broker Plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/util/LoggingBrokerPlugin.html).  From the vague information you've given on what you want to log and where this seems like the best option.  A broker plugin gives you access to messages entering and exiting broker queues and as such you could log whatever information you find is useful to your use case.

Comment: I want to configure ActiveMQ is such a way that, it will write all incoming messages, Publisher name (hostname) into log file. Also I want to write Consumer name (hostname) which dequeue message from ActiveMQ into log file.

Comment: As I said that's something you have to implement yourself as logging that as normal is a security hole waiting to happen